# hibernate versioning issuing update statment for no reason

Tags: hibernate

My hibernate versioning is issuing an update statement for no apparent reason.

In my BankAccount mapping file:

```
<version type="dbtimestamp" name="modified" column="Modified"/>
```

inthe AvailableBalance mapping file:

```
<many-to-one name="bankAccount" class="model.businessdomain.orm.BankAccount" fetch="select" >
   <column name="BankAccountId" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

The resulting sql statements issued, when a select is done from the AvailableBalance table (via a function):

```
17:12:16,152 DEBUG SQL:401 - select * from dbo.get_availablebalancelist(?) ab  where ab.bankAccountId = ?
17:12:31,539 DEBUG SQL:401 - select current_timestamp
17:12:31,625 DEBUG SQL:401 - update dbo.BankAccount set Modified=?, BankAccountTypeId=?, BankID=?, InterestSchemeID=?, BankAccNo=?, SysParamID=?, BankAccName=?, BranchCode=?, UserRef=?, CAMSCode=?, Provision=?, ProvisionPerc=?, OverDraftLimit=?, isIslamic=?, Active=? where BankAccountId=? and Modified=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the object being modified in memory in any way after the select? If the object is marked at dirty, depending on your transaction strategy, a commit may be occurring which could be implicitly updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that update is most probably not in the code you posted.

To debug it, you could set a break point in your logging facility, and look at the stack that issues this statement.